# How can I normalize a histogram such that the sum of the heights is equal to 1?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I generated the figure below using the a call to `matplotlib.pyplot.hist` in which I passed the kwarg `normed=True`:

[image]

Upon further research, I realized that this kind of normalization works in such a way that the integral of the histogram is equal to 1.  How can I plot this same data such that the sum of the heights of the bars equals 1?

In other words, I want each bit to represent the proportion of the whole that its values contain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a straightforward way, but
you can manually divide all bar heights by the length of the input (the following is made in `ipython --pylab` to skip the imports):

```
inp = normal(size=1000)
h = hist(inp)
```

Which gives you

[image]

Now, you can do:

```
bar(h[1][:-1], h[0]/float(len(inp)), diff(h[1]))
```

and get

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  Could you please explain what each element in the tuple returned from `hist` is?  Your `bar(h[1][:-1], h[0]/float(len(inp)), diff(h[1]))` leaves me a bit confused!

Comment: @blz [`hist`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist) returns `heights` and `x points` as first two elements of the tuple. [`bar`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar) takes `left` and `top` as first two arguments.

Comment: Thanks!  I ran your code on my data, but I don't seem to be getting a normalized histogram =/  [Here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/6160029/normR.pickle) is the data (PANDAS DataFrame object), and [here](http://www.hastebin.com/ponagaciji.py) is the code I used. Also, [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/6160029/normHist_fail.png) is the graph I get. Any idea what I did incorrectly?

Comment: @blz Unfortunately, I don't have `pandas` and don't know how to use it. Can you try your code on a regular list first?

Comment: I tried it on my data in list-form, but I get the same result.  [Here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/6160029/data_listform.pickle)'s a pickled version of the list, if you can make any sense of it =/

Comment: My code works fine for this list on my system. [Here](http://i.imgur.com/fTnDT.png) is what I get (using `bins=20` in `hist`). But when I paste your function in the `ipython` session and call it, I also see only the non-normed histogram. I think it's shown after the call to `hist`, and then `bar` doesn't show anything because there's already an open window. Try running it as a script adding appropriate calls to `figure()` and `show()`.